# octobercms api Image path

Tags: laravel, rest, api, octobercms

I want to create API from my plugin but API returns all I need expect image paths. Do you know anyone how to get image paths and return in my API?

In my routes.php I have

```
<?php
use Mycompany\ArubaPlaces\Models\Places;

Route::get('api/places', function(){
$places = Places::All();
return $places;
});
```

And this is my modelI have this relation. I need "placeimages" paths in my API:

```
public $attachMany = [
        'placesimages' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

fields.yaml

```
fields:
name:
    label: Title
    span: auto
    required: 1
    type: text
slug:
    label: Slug
    span: auto
    preset:
        field: name
        type: slug
    type: text
description:
    label: Description
    size: small
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    span: full
    type: richeditor
latitude:
    label: Latitude
    span: auto
    required: 1
    type: text
longitude:
    label: Longitude
    span: auto
    required: 1
    type: text
placesimages:
    label: 'Place images'
    mode: image
    useCaption: true
    thumbOptions:
        mode: crop
        extension: auto
    span: full
    type: fileupload

active:
    label: Aktívne
    span: auto
    type: switch
```

Comment: what do you get in response?  can you add response object too?

Comment: {
"0": {
"id": 29,
"latitude": "12.574850",
"longitude": "-70.043459",
"name": "Arubiana Office",
"description": "<p>While having ...</p>",
"category": "category1",
"slug": "arubiana",
"sort_order": 1,
"routes_id": null,
"route_id": null,
"active": 1,
}}

Answer (score 1):

1) First option is adding `protected $with = ['placesimages'];` to your `Places` model to eager load the desired relationships, here you can add more than one relation by default.

2) You can do the eager loading in your query e.g `Places::with('placesimages')->get();` if you do not want to eager load all files by default. Also here `with` accepts an array of relations.

If you are sure that in your app everytime you query a place you want to fetch the images then go for option one, otherwise, option 2 will only get the images when only you specify it in the query builder.

Read more about [eager loading](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#eager-loading)